# How To Do jQuery Selection For This DIV

Tags: php, javascript

I have this div tags :

```
<div id="target-share">
<a href="#" title="" id="to-chosen" class="default"><span class="to-admin">Admin</span></a>
<ul id="select-shareto">
<li data-val="0-1">
<a href="#" title="" class="selected"><span class="to-Finance">Finance</span></a>
</li>
<li data-val="1-1">
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-admin-private">Admin Private</span></a>
</li>
<li data-val="1-0">
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-ceo">CEO</span></a>
</li>
<li data-val="0-0">
<a href="#" title=""><span class="to-ceo-private">CEO Private</span></a>
</li>                                    
</ul>
<input id="shareto" type="text" value="0-1" name="shareto">
</div><!-- #target-share -->
```

and this JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
        $('ul li').click(function() {
            $('input#shareto').val($(this).data('val'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

that JavaScript actually works when I'm using it with that div alone. but when I put it on my full code, that JavaScript doesn't work. I think that because there are more than one UL and LI tags on my code.

Now, the question is... how to apply that Javascript so that it can works ONLY for that div, even though there are other UL and LI tags.

Comment: what do you mean by "JavaScript" doesn't work? it runs for all the *ul>li* instead of *#target-share>ul>li* in such case Jon Taylor solution should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this instead targeting the div first then its contents

```
$('#target-share ul li')
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (not just Jquery) is all about scoping:

`$('ul li').click(function() {`

Causes that `click` to bind to every `li` in a `ul` so what you wanna do is scope the `click` down to a specific area of your page or set of elements across the page.

To scope it down to a specific element the best idea is to use a id like so:

`$('#target-share ul li')`

But to scope it down to a number of elements it is better to use a class like:

`$('.target-share ul li')`

Edit:

Also `on()` could be a good replacement here for `click` but it depends on where the HTML is being sourced and how it is being used, but thought I would make you aware of that function in case you didn't already know about it.

Answer (score -1):

Select those `ul li` that have your `data-val` attribute:

```
$(function($) {
    $('ul li[data-val]').click(function() {
        $('input#shareto').val($(this).data('val'));
    });
});
```

Comment: surely this would not work if the other divs also had 'data-val' attributes in their ul li elements?

Comment: The selector `ul li[data-val]` has nothing to do with `div` elements. It will select all `li` elements with the `data-val` attribute, that are also children of `ul` elements.

Comment: Which is exactly my point. He wants the `ul li` only within this div not every one on the page.  And since he has not posted the code for the other divs how can you assume that those ones dont have ul li elements with the data-val attribute?  The only safe thing to assume is that since the div has an id we should only select children of this div using its id.

Comment: You're right. His code makes me think that even he isn't quite sure of what he wants though.

Comment: I am pretty sure (well ok 99% sure) that your code isn't what he asked for though, I mean no where does he specify he is using the `data` attribute or a `val` sub attribute within that data attribute. Also shouldn't attributes be searched via: `$('ul li[attr=data-val]')` or something along those lines.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (well ok 99%) that you're both right. Downvotes, away!